# GO TO in FORTRAN 77

Tags: fortran

I want to translate a code written in FORTRAN 77 to Fortran 90.
Here is the code i want to translate but i don't understand go to syntax.

```
FUNCTION YRR(L1,L2,L,CT1,CT2,DP)

      IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
      
      PI=dacos(-1d0)
      
      XL1=L1
      XL2=L2
      XL=L
      DEN=SQRT(4.D0*PI)*2.D0*PI
      FACT=((2.D0*XL+1.D0)/DEN)*PARITII(L1+L2)

      M=0
      
      SUM=THRJ(XL1,XL2,XL,dble(0),dble(0),dble(0))*PLM(L1,0,CT1)*PLM(L2,0,CT2)*FACT
 2000 M=M+1
      IF (M.Gt.min(l1,l2)) GO TO 3000
      SUM=SUM+2.D0*PARITii(M)*THRJ(XL1,XL2,XL,dble(M),dble(-M),dble(0)) &
              *PLM(L1,M,CT1)*PLM(L2,M,CT2)*COS(dble(M)*DP)*FACT
              
      GO TO 2000
        
 3000 YRR=SUM
      RETURN
 
      END
```

I tried to translate but the sum is not working as a sum of products.

```
FUNCTION YRR(L1, L2, L, CT1, CT2, DP)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: L1, L2, L
  REAL(8), INTENT(IN) :: CT1, CT2, DP
  REAL(8) :: YRR
  REAL(8), PARAMETER :: PI = ACOS(-1.0d0)
  REAL(8) :: XL1, XL2, XL, DEN, FACT
  INTEGER :: M
  REAL(8) :: SUM
  XL1 = L1
  XL2 = L2
  XL = L
  DEN = SQRT(4.0d0 * PI) * 2.0d0 * PI
  FACT = ((2.0d0 * XL + 1.0d0) / DEN) * PARITII(L1 + L2)
  M = 0
  SUM = THRJ(XL1, XL2, XL, 0.0d0, 0.0d0, 0.0d0) * PLM(L1, 0, CT1) * PLM(L2, 0, CT2) * FACT
  DO WHILE (M <= MIN(L1, L2))
    M = M + 1
    SUM = SUM + 2.0d0 * PARITii(M) * THRJ(XL1, XL2, XL, M, -M, 0.0d0) &
        * PLM(L1, M, CT1) * PLM(L2, M, CT2) * COS(M * DP) * FACT
  END DO
  YRR = SUM
  RETURN
END FUNCTION YRR
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: GOTO 500  jumps to the line with the label 500 in the code.  To get rid of GOTO you need to use DO WHILE or IF or FOR  so that the control flow is the same.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Read the short descriptiins of tags you are adding. Normally do not not use multiple version tag. Be aware that Fortran 90 is completely obsolete and the oldes revisiin considered by compilers is Fortran 95 but even that one is almost 30 years old and dated. Also be aware that using `REAL(8)` is ugly, not portable and is not the same as double precision https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Comment: In the initial version the test on `M` comes after the increment by 1, but in your version the tests comes before the increment. If you want to keep the `do while` approach, then you have to slightly adapt the test: `DO WHILE (M+1 <= MIN(L1, L2))`

Comment: You can just write the loop as `Do m = 1, Min( l1, l2 )`, which would the more "Fortranic" way of doing it. Also you haven't declared `PARITii` or `PLM` - is your new code i a module you haven't shown us? And very much a second to @VladimirFГероямслава re: avoidance of real( 8 ). Be aware it might not even be supported by a compiler.

Comment: @IanBush I though about that, but appaarently `PLM()` is  a function, and it can possibly modify `L1` and `L2` during the loop.

Comment: Either way it needs declaring *somewhere* if implicit none is in scope

Comment: Indeed the translated code won't compile (unless it is part of a module that contains `PLM()` or uses a module that contains it). The original one will, because of the implicit mapping

Comment: Ah, impure functions. Sorry you are right, I try to forget about those as I like to sleep at night

Answer (score 0):

The pair of `GOTO` statements are giving you an infinite loop with an escape.  Modern Fortran (with the exception of using `dble` and an `implicit` statement) would do

```
function yrr(l1, l2, l, ct1, ct2, dp)

   implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
      
   pi = acos(-1.d0)
      
   xl1 = l1
   xl2 = l2
   xl = l
   den = 4 * sqrt(pi) * pi
   fact = ((2 * xl + 1) / den) * paritii(l1 + l2)

   m = 0
      
   sum = thrj(xl1,xl2,xl,dble(0),dble(0),dble(0)) &
   &   * plm(l1,0,ct1) * plm(l2,0,ct2) * fact
   do
      m = m+1
      if (m > min(l1,l2)) exit
      sum = sum + 2 * paritii(m) &
      &   * thrj(xl1,xl2,xl,dble(m),dble(-m),dble(0)) &
          * plm(l1,m,ct1) * plm(l2,m,ct2) * cos(m * dp) * fact
   end do
        
   yrr=sum

end function yrr
```

Comment: Dear all thank you for your answers. @steve, please is it possible to use one do loop for m ?the first sum is for m=0 and the second for m=1, min(l1,l2). The analytical form is YRR=A(Sum0+Sum). plm , thr, paritii are the functions. My goal is the implement YRR line by line with respect of the value of m.

Comment: @Mekobi, Sorry I don't understand your comment.  In the code I wrote, there is only 1 do-loop.  The statement labeled with 2000 and the `GOTO 2000` statement in original form an infinite loop.  That infinite loop is broken by the if-statement and `GOTO 3000`.  The code I wrote breaks the infinite loop with the `EXIT` statement.

Comment: I ask whether is it possible to write `YRR=SUM1+SUM2'. When m=0 i have the first sum and m/=0 i have the second sum but with the same `(l1,l2,l)`. I wan to implement this function YRR as a sum-of-product respect of m.

Comment: here is the link of my input data. I want to write YRR as SUM1+SUM2 using one do loop. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lwqpMyFiKkvm8cMSbBFoyxUKVmMknblN?usp=drive_link